# Why i get this error from google map V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I write simple app to show map in google map,my code this :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final LatLng LATLNG_IRAN = new LatLng(32.379961, 54.005356);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LATLNG_IRAN, 4));


    }



}
```

but when i run the app i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jx.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.nB(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.behzad.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
```

in this line:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LATLNG_IRAN, 4));
```

How can i solve that?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448378/java-lang-nullpointerexception-cameraupdatefactory-is-not-initialized-logcat-ex

Comment: just to make sure, you have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'` in your `build.gradle`, right?